# how to store sql query value into array

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim sql As String = "Select ProductID From OrderDetail Order By ProductID Desc"
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
```

How do i store all the productid that i have retrieve into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)

Using reader As SqlDataReader = command .ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        list.Add(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductID")))
    End While
End Using
'check  list.ToArray() now
```

**EDIT :** But, Instead of return an Array, i Would return a **Generic List** of Integers (if you only want to return the ProductId) or A List of `ProductClass` objects

```
Private Function GetProductIDs() As IList(Of Integer)

    Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim conStr = "write your connection string here"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(conStr )
        Dim sql As String = "Select ProductID From OrderDetail Order By ProductID Desc"
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                list.Add(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductID")))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using

    Return list

End Function
```

**EDIT 2** : *As per the comment,* 
To retrieve an put in the Text of a label, you can do this

```
Dim str As String
str = String.Join(",", GetProductIDs())
Label1.Text=str;
```

Assuming `Label1` is theI D of your label control.The `String.Join` method will return a string of ProductId's seperated by comma like `"1,2,6,7"`

Comment: How do i retrieve all the values from the list to a label.text?

Comment: 'While reader.Read()
            Sum.Text = (reader("ProductID"))
        End While
        Loop While reader.NextResult() '

Comment: Hey, how do i get the first 3 items from the list?

Comment: @FredHomme: Either you can update your query to return the `TOP 3` items or apply the `TAKE` function on the list we have

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLdr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader 'Gets Data

While dr.Read() 'While Data is Present        
      MsgBox(dr("Column Name")) 'Show data in a Message Box
End While

Loop While SQLdr.NextResult() 'Move to the Next Record
```

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/code/216920/sql-in-vb.net